# Count the number of occurrences of 7 in a number given by the user

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
while (a) {

        b.push(a % 10);
        a = Math.floor(a / 10);
        if (b == 7) {
            n = n + 1;
        }
        console.log("<br><br>number of 7's:" + n);

    }
```

This is what I have come up with. The output is one of the numbers has seven; if not, then zero. I want the program to count the number of times seven appears in a number.

Comment: There is something wrong with `b`. In line `b.push(a % 10);` you treat it as an array but then you do `if (b == 7)` treating it as a number. What is it ?

Comment: fastest way is convert your number to string and count chars like this: `a.toString().split('7').length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to a string, and then count how many times a character = 7:

```js
let n = 7326577
let cnt = 0;

let strN = '' + n;

for(let c of strN)
  if(c == '7')
    cnt ++

console.log('Number of 7\'s in number: ' + cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following you approach you need to store the last digit to a different variable and use that for checking if it is a 7

```js
var a = 709728457;
var b = [];
var n = 0;

while (a) {
  const lastDigit = a % 10;
  b.push(lastDigit); // if you still need to store all digits
  a = Math.floor(a / 10);
  if (lastDigit == 7) {
    n = n + 1;
  }
}

console.log("number of 7's:" + n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 7686774737
var no = String(a).split('').filter(e=>e==7).length;
console.log(no)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).